# Finding one-loop box Feynman integral solution

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, feynman-diagrams

I am searching for a way to calculate a one-loop box integral as in the figure. I am curious about is there any solution already exist for this integral that I can use instead of calculating from the beginning.

[image]

Another question is that is there analytical solution or I can only get numerical solutions for this type of integrals? and which program or package I can use to get to the solution.

Integral looks like this
$ \int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{ig_{\mu\nu}}{k^2}(-ig\gamma^\mu)\frac{i(\gamma.(p-k)+m)}{(p-k)^2-m^2}(-ig\gamma^\alpha)\frac{ig_{\alpha\beta}}{(p'-p+k)^2}(-ig\gamma^\beta)\frac{i(\gamma.(q+k)+m)}{(q+k)^2-m^2}(-g\gamma^\nu)$ but my aim to calculate with different coupling constant to test different theory as

$ \int\frac{d^4k}{(2\pi)^4}\frac{ig_{\mu\nu}}{k^2}(-ig\gamma^\mu\gamma^5)\frac{i(\gamma.(p-k)+m)}{(p-k)^2-m^2}(-ig\gamma^\alpha\gamma^5)\frac{ig_{\alpha\beta}}{(p'-p+k)^2}(-ig\gamma^\beta\gamma^5)\frac{i(\gamma.(q+k)+m)}{(q+k)^2-m^2}(-g\gamma^\nu\gamma^5)$

Comment: In which theory? QED?

Comment: Yes, QED. fermions and photons.

Comment: You're going to have to label the particles and make sure they obey the appropriate Feynman rules, it would be good practice for you to write down the matrix element associated with this diagram.

Comment: The exact answer can be obtained with the help of [Package-X](https://packagex.hepforge.org).  However, for general kinematics and mass, the result is very complicated.

Answer (score 1):

In my view, one of the best tools to calculalte complicated loop diagrams is dispersion relation method. You should to the following steps:

1. Write down the expression for diagram with you Feynman rules
2. Carefully simplify numerator: do trace, make contractions, etc (please check numerator, there is a trace, isn't it?).
3. You will obtain an expression $N^{\mu\nu}/D$, where $N^{\mu\nu}$ is numerator and $D$ is denominator, which consists of "propagators"
4. Then you can contract indices of $N^{\mu\nu}$ and obtain an expression for $N=g^{\mu\nu}N_{\mu\nu}$ (I suppose that tensor structure of $N^{\mu\nu}$ will be clear after step 2).

Now you are ready to calculate the integral. Explicitly pick out integral over $k^0$ (0-component of momentum in loop) and write down $k^2=(k^0)^2-{\bf k}^2$. Carefully analyze poles of $D$ with $\epsilon$-prescription and draw them in complex plane. You should see that there is a branch cut for this integral for specific values of momenta. Then, you can check that this branch cut defines discontinuity of the integral over $k^0$, I denote it as $\Delta I$. This discontinuity relates to imaginary part of the integral as $\Delta I = 2i\,\mathrm{Im}\,I$. Then, you can find imaginary part of the integral, perform integration over ${\bf k}$ and find an expression for imaginary part for you diagram. Finally, using dispersion relation, you can restore full expression for diagram.

If you find this brief description of calculation convenient and familiar, you can check paragraphs 111, 113, 115 (how to use dispersion relation for diagrams in QED) and 126 (how to use double dispersion relation for "box" diagrams) of Landau's course in theoretical physics, 4th volume . In the last paragraph you can find consideration of you diagram but with QED Feynman rules. Later I may be write down explicit calculation for your diagram.

Comment: "Then you can contract indices of $N^{\mu\nu}$ and obtain an expression for $N=g^{\mu\nu}N_{\mu\nu}$", you can't  do the contraction before the integration! A counterexample: 2D QED (Schwinger model), where careless contraction of indices will produce a zero vacuum polarization which is actually non-zero if done properly (via. eg. dimensional regularization and integration).

Comment: @MadMax it was wrong. I emphasize that my answer is only sketch and I refer to the book.